# grep from a specific value to specific value

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

For example, I have a file with data:

```
[2023-03-21 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-21 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-22 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-25 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
```

and I want to grep all lines which includes values from **2023-03-22** to **2023-03-26**

so, I want to grep its lines

```
[2023-03-22 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-25 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
```

### How can I do it with grep or maybe with sed or awk?

And another case:

I have a file with data

```
[2023-03-21 00:45:20 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-21 01:10:11 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-21 02:04:56 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-21 12:09:15 +0000] some_data
...
...
in this part the lines with the next data with some_data
...
...
[2023-03-23 21:40:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 22:15:11 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 23:40:06 +0000] some_data
```

How I can grep lines from **[2023-03-21 01:10:11 +0000]** some_data to **[2023-03-23 22:15:11 +0000] some_data**

Maybe Can I grep with flag -n ? I get the number of string for [2023-03-21 01:10:11 +0000] and then grep value [2023-03-23 22:15:11 +0000] with flag -n. Its command back me numbers of line for these lines.

And how can I get massive of date from specific line to spicific line if I know number of lines?

Comment: For this specific instance, you can do `grep 2023-03-2[2-6] input.txt | grep something_specific`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to specify the characters you want in that spot as members of a "bracket expression":

```
grep '2023-03-2[23456]' file_name
```

When you're looking for a set of characters that are consecutive in the sorting/collation scheme (as you are with your dates), you can use a range in the bracket expression:

```
grep '2023-03-2[2-6]' file_name
```

More complex ways to match the contents of the lines are available, but your question is handled by a nice, simple bracket expression.

Comment: The "more complex" matching techniques would make a good answer.

Comment: @RonJohn, true, but as far as I can tell, it would be an answer to a different question.

Comment: Your answer is what I put in a comment.  Didn't make it an answer because it's *too specific*.

Comment: The question was specific about matching the range of dates, and omitted any need to match other fields.  My answer was specific where the question was specific.  (the question was updated with a new request since I submitted my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I founded an answer: If I want to print massive of data from file - from value to value, so I can use command sed in this case:

```
sed -n '/\[2023-03-21 01:10:11/,/\[2023-03-23 22:15:11/p' file_name
```

I forgot that sed it's a stream editor for string data.

Comment: That would fail if either of those specific timestamps did not exist in the input - don't do exact comparisons like that when trying to match within a range, use `<=` and/or `>=` comparisons instead (which you can't do with sed so use awk) so your code will work even if the exact range start/end strings are not present in the input, e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741504/133219.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]' '("2023-03-22" <= $2) && ($2 <= "2023-03-26")' file
[2023-03-22 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-23 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-25 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
```

Consider how trivial it'd be to modify that for any requirements, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[][ ]' '("2023-03-26" <= $2)' file
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-29 12:27:19 +0000] some_data

$ awk -F'[][ ]' '("2023-03-26" == $2)' file
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data

$ awk -F'[][ ]' '("2023-03-22" == $2) || ("2023-03-26" == $2)' file
[2023-03-22 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
[2023-03-26 12:27:19 +0000] some_data
```